# Is there a way to embed a twitter feed, but hide most recent tweet, and display "second-most-recent" tweet first?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, embed

I need to embed and display a user's most recent tweets, but hide the most recent one.
Display tweets 2-10 but hide tweet 1.

I'm aware of Twitter's API docs, but this seems to be an odd request, and isn't covered in there.
I tried testing with data-tweet-limit="2-10" but this doesn't affect playout correctly.

Ideally would like COLUMN 1 to be first tweet, COLUMN 2 to be second tweet.

Added functionality such as skipping retweets and videos would be fantastic if possible.

### This is the embed code:

```
    HTML:
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
            <title>Twitter Embed</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#141d26;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-tweet-limit="1" data-theme="dark" data-chrome="noheader, nofooter, transparent, noborders" width="720" href="https://twitter.com/lfc" data-widget-id="test"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-tweet-limit="1" data-theme="dark" data-chrome="noheader, nofooter, transparent, noborders" width="720" href="https://twitter.com/lfc" data-widget-id="test"></a>
            </div>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
                    
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
    
--------------------------------------------------------
CSS:

    
.column {
float: right;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin-bottom: -5%;
margin-top: 1%;
padding-top: 1%;
}

.row {
content: "";
width: 90%;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 2%;
display: inline-table;
clear: both;
}

.timeline-TweetList-tweet:first-of-type { 
display:none; 
}
```

---

JS:

```
!function(d,s,id){
  var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
  }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: Your best bet is probably the most complicated and that is use a server side programming language like PHP to use Twitter's API to access the user's timeline.